# No qualifying bean of type ... available for Repository class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting a no qualifying bean error as detailed below. I thought if I pointed the basePackages attribute on the @EnableJpaRepositories to the package containing the repositories, it would figure it out. I'm sure it's something very simple I'm missing. Some of you have asked for the project structure but I'm limited in what I can provide for IP reasons. Nonetheless, I added application.properties and a pom.xml

```
2021-04-14 01:03:20 DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.cloud.file.generator.domain.model.CostDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1716)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.mycomp.myprj.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.CostFileGeneratorApplication.main(BlueCostSSCFileGeneratorApplication.java:22)
2021-04-14 01:03:20 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
```

CostDataRepository interface:

```
package com.mycomp.cloud.file.generator.domain.model;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CostDataRepository extends CrudRepository<CostData, Long> {

    List<CostData> findByCostDataIdGreaterThanOrderByCostDataIdAsc(Long lastId);
}
```

Relevant datasource  configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.mycomp.cloud.file.generator.domain.model"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    private String dataSourceUrl;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String driver;
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.mycomp.cloud.ssc.file.generator.domain.model"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("your_name");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
//        properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jd_metadata_defaults",
//                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.use_jd_metadata_defaults." + NAME));

        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }
    @Autowired
    public DataSourceConfig(@Value("${upload_datasource_url}") String upload_datasource_url,
            @Value("${upload_datasource_username}") String upload_datasource_username,
            @Value("${upload_datasource_password}") String upload_datasource_password,
            @Value("${upload_datasource_driver}") String upload_datasource_driver) {
        this.dataSourceUrl = upload_datasource_url;
        this.userName = upload_datasource_username;
        this.password = upload_datasource_password;
        this.driver = upload_datasource_driver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "uploadDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(dataSourceUrl)
                .username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .driverClassName(driver).build();

    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=sprint-vault-services-not-available
spring.application.name=ssc-file-generator
file.generator.schema=FILE_GENERATOR

spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.schemas=${file.generator.schema}
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=false

file-generator.date-format=MMddyy
file-generator.time-format=HHmmss
file-generator.ebcdic-output-path=app/output/ebcdic
file-generator.csv-output-path=app/output/csv
file-generator.header-timestamp-format=yyyyMMddHHmmss
file-generator.file-sequence-number=1

logging.path=app/logs

bcupload_datasource_url=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_URL}
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=FILE_GENERATOR
bcupload_datasource_username=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
bcupload_datasource_password=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
bcupload_datasource_driver=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_DRIVER}
bcupload_datasource_flyway_db_name=LocalFileGenerator

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_DRIVER}
spring.datasource.url=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.password=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.username=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.jpa.database-platform=DB2Platform
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
 End old bcupload datasource

# Begin test DB trial
#spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:mem:emp-systemdb
#spring.datasource.driverClassName= org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.username= admin
#spring.datasource.password= admin
#spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl= true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop
# End test db trial 

 

spring.flyway.url= ${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.flyway.user=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.flyway.password=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycomp.cloud.cost</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssc-file-generator</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>SSC File Generator</name>
    <description>This project is for creating a file encoded in EBCID to send it to SSC.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH.mm.ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <build.version>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.version>
        <db2.driver.version>10.5.9</db2.driver.version>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            **/SSCFileGeneratorApplication.java,**/RunnerConfiguration.java
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
            <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*Should.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/unit/java</source>
                                <source>src/test/acceptance/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-tests-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>src/test/unit/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>src/test/acceptance/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/acceptance/java</testSourceDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is weird, are there any other errors on the log? Can you share the structure of your application?

Comment: Why do you configure datasource and entitymanagerfactory?

Comment: Is the configuration actually used? How do you ensure it gets picked up?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I had a different question which I also asked about on SO wherein it complained about not having an entityManagerFactoryBuilder. Spring seems to insist on having spring.datasource defined, we also have Flyway which insists on a different datasource in application.properties. Finally, we had some code which uses jdbcTemplate from the datasource. In many cases they point to the same db.

Comment: @JensSchauder I don't think it's making a connection, but do think it's trying to, but doesn't like some aspect of the configuration. I believe this because of the stack trace shown.

Comment: @albertjtan I added some extra items, but can't add too much for IP reasons.